# Form submission content won't show up until I destroy the session

Tags: php, sql, session, sql-update

I have multiply `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['differentthings']; ?>` on my current project.

Problem: When I update the SQL through the form, I can only see the changes through the database and **not in the value**. To see the new **value** I have to **destroy the session** I am on and then update the webbrowser to see it.

- Is there any way of updating the session data without destroying the session first?
- Can the problem possibly be that I am calling `ob_start();` right before `session_start();` on top?

Best regards. Nabil

Comment: How about just assigning it at the same time you're updating the database without destroying the session? Or am I misunderstanding the question entirely?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I am assigning it with $_SESSION['differentthings']; , It's taken from the db.

Comment: But are you only assigning it if it's not already set?

Answer (score 0):

can you show your code that you used, but from the information given it sounds like you just need to reassign the session variable that you are trying to display,

```
$_SESSION['differentthings'] = 'first value';
echo $_SESSION['differentthings']; // this will display first value
$_SESSION['differentthings'] = 'second value';
echo $_SESSION['differentthings']; // this will display second value
```